# OpenGL - Show Texture Only

Tags: python, opengl

I'm working on a 2D isometric game, using pygame and pyopengl.

I'm drawing sprites as quads, with a texture. I managed to get the alpha transparency to work for the texture, but the quad itself is still filled in a solid color (whatever colour gl pipeline is set with at the time).

How do I hide the quad shape, and just show the texture?

Here is a pic showing the problem (gl pipeline set to pink/purple color):

[image]

The code is a bit messy, and I've been blindly copy 'n pasting gl calls hoping it solves the problem so there are bound to be quite a few calls in the wrong place or duplicated (or both).

GL Setup code (called once at start of script)

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
glLoadIdentity()
glViewport(0, 0, screen_size[0], screen_size[1])
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glLoadIdentity()
glOrtho(0.0, screen_size[0], 0.0, screen_size[1], 0.0, 1.0)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadIdentity()
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING)
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
```

Drawing setup code (called once at the start of each frame)

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
glLoadIdentity()
glViewport(0, 0, screen_size[0], screen_size[1])
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glLoadIdentity()
glOrtho(0.0, screen_size[0], 0.0, screen_size[1], 0.0, 1.0)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadIdentity()
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING)
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
```

Quad draw code (called for every sprite draw call):

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST)
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL)

# Start new transformation matrix
glPushMatrix()

# Apply translation
glTranslatef(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery, 0.0)

# Start gl drawing cursor
glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)

# Bind the texture to this draw session
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.texture.id)

# Start drawing a quad
glBegin(GL_QUADS)

# Grab new copy of rect, and move to the origin
r = self.rect.copy()
r.center = (0, 0)

# Draw top left point
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0)
glVertex2f(*r.topleft)

# Draw top right point
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0)
glVertex2f(*r.topright)

# Draw bottom right point
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0)
glVertex2f(*r.bottomright)

# Draw bottom left point
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0)
glVertex2f(*r.bottomleft)

# End quad
glEnd()

# Apply transformation matrix
glPopMatrix()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colored background behind your tiles is probably due to this line when you set up your texture:

```
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL)
```

Just remove this as the default texture environment settings are probably fine for standard tile rendering. As an example of what messing with these parameters can do, if you wanted `glColor` calls to "tint" your texture instead, then replace `GL_DECAL` with `GL_BLEND`.

There is no need for any of those lighting calls included in your code as far as I can tell unless you are working with 3d models and ancient per-vertex lighting (I assume you are not since this is a 2d isometric game). Also you only need blending for this, no need for alpha testing. Assuming you are working with images with alpha (RGBA format), here is a simple demo that displays two tiles with a transparent background (supply your own image of course instead of `./images/grass.png`):

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
import sys

class Sprite(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.width = 0
        self.height = 0 
        self.texture = glGenTextures(1)

    def load_texture(self, texture_url):
        tex = pygame.image.load(texture_url)
        tex_surface = pygame.image.tostring(tex, 'RGBA')
        tex_width, tex_height = tex.get_size()
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.texture)
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, tex_width, tex_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tex_surface)
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)
        self.width = tex_width
        self.height = tex_height

    def set_position(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def render(self):
        #glColor(1, 1, 1, 1)
        glEnable(GL_BLEND)
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.texture)
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        glTexCoord(0, 0)
        glVertex(self.x, self.y, 0)
        glTexCoord(0, 1)
        glVertex(self.x, self.y + self.height, 0)
        glTexCoord(1, 1)
        glVertex(self.x + self.width, self.y + self.height, 0)
        glTexCoord(1, 0)
        glVertex(self.x + self.width, self.y, 0)
        glEnd()
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)

def init_gl():
    window_size = width, height = (550, 400)
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_mode(window_size, OPENGL | DOUBLEBUF)
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, -1, 1)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    init_gl()
    tile1 = Sprite()
    tile1.load_texture("./images/grass.png")
    tile1.set_position(50, 100)
    tile2 = Sprite()
    tile2.load_texture("./images/grass.png")
    tile2.set_position(80, 130)
    tiles = [tile1, tile2]

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        glColor(1, 0, 0, 1)
        for tile in tiles:
            tile.render()
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I managed to get it working properly. Only thing now (although this was always a problem) is the performance is slow. I was hoping moving from SDL based to opengl would give me a boost, but its not really much different. I have about 1000 64x64 tile sprites on a 1280x960 screen I redraw constantly and I get around 17fps. Is there something major I'm doing wrong, or do I just need to move away from the pipeline method?

Comment: I would try out the advice over [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/30365/78005). As stated in that answer, one simple starting improvement would be to reduce texture switching as much as possible (i.e. minimize calling glBindTexture by ordering the list of tiles). The most important fix, however, is to group all of your tiles into a vertex buffer object (VBO) and render it with a single draw call. Rendering quads one by one is extremely slow and uses the old immediate mode.

Answer (score 2):

Well, either use *blending*, so that the alpha value actually has effect on opacity. Or use alpha testing, so that incoming fragments with an alpha below/above a certain threshold are discarded.

Blending requires to sort geometry back to front. And given what you want to do alpha testing may be the easier, more straightforward solution.

**Update:**

Either way it's imperative that the texture's alpha value makes it through to the fragment. If you were using shaders this would be as simple as making sure that the fragment output alpha would receive its value from the texture. But you're using the fixed function pipeline and the mess that's the texture environment state machine.

Using only a single texture your best bet would be a GL_REPLACE texture mode (completely ignores the vertex color). Or GL_MODULATE that takes the vertex color into account. Right now you're assumingly using GL_DECAL mode.

My suggestion: Drop the fixed function pipeline and use shaders. Much easier to get things related to texturing working. Also you'll hard pressed to find hardware that's not using shaders anyway (unless you're planning to run your program on stuff that's been built before 2004).

Comment: I thought the glEnable (BLEND) calls were enabling alpha blending. What am I missing?

Comment: @Oliver: Damn, I missed, that. My bad.

Comment: Can you recommend any tutorials on the shader method for 2d stuff? All the stuff I've found and read so far has been using the old method, especially for 2D.

Comment: @Oliver: There's no conceptual difference between 2D and 3D in OpenGL. Technically it always boils down to drawing points, lines or triangles, one at a time on a 2D framebuffer. And what makes the whole thing "3D" is, how the position of the vertices on the 2D framebuffer are determined from coordinates in a higher dimensional space. For what's it worth any tutorial regarding 3D graphics and shaders will do for you and the only thing you have to keep in your mind, that one of the coordinates (which one is your choice) is constant for all operations.